# 500 internal server error deploying Django-Wagtail application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have tried everything I can think of and I have gone through [the AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) and [RealPython](https://realpython.com/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) guides. I am honestly at a loss.

I have developed an application and it functions perfectly on my local machine, using a pipenv lockfile. Because of this there was no immediate need for a requirements.txt, however EB requires one and so, with the pipenv environment open I ran

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

to create one. It now contains:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.13.2
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.8
defusedxml==0.6.0
Django==2.1.1
django-allauth==0.40.0
django-modelcluster==4.4.1
django-taggit==0.24.0
django-treebeard==4.3.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0
draftjs-exporter==2.1.7
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.8
oauthlib==3.1.0
Pillow==5.4.1
pycparser==2.19
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.2.0
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
Unidecode==1.1.1
urllib3==1.25.7
wagtail==2.5.2
webencodings==0.5.1
Willow==1.1
```

I had to downgrade to Django 2.1.1 because someone said that there are versioning issues with EB at 2.2. I am using python 3.6.8.

I was receiving an error stating that "WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist", I fixed this using

```
eb config
```

and searching for wsgi and changing the path to

```
application_name/wsgi.py
```

Now, upon running

```
eb create
eb deploy
```

I receive the output

```
Creating application version archive "app-60c1-200116_214620".
Uploading application_name/app-60c1-200116_214620.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
2020-01-16 19:46:35    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2020-01-16 19:46:38    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2020-01-16 19:47:00    INFO    New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
2020-01-16 19:47:00    INFO    Environment update completed successfully.
```

I have also added the url into ALLOWED_HOSTS in base.py (wagtail version of settings.py).

The application works locally but when I run it on the server I receive a 500 internal service error. The following is some of the contents of the log file:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Thu Jan 16 19:40:47.104485 2020] [:error] [pid 4284] [remote 127.0.0.1:18388] mod_wsgi (pid=4284): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/educess/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jan 16 19:40:47.104591 2020] [:error] [pid 4284] [remote 127.0.0.1:18388] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jan 16 19:40:47.104624 2020] [:error] [pid 4284] [remote 127.0.0.1:18388]   File "/opt/python/current/app/educess/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Thu Jan 16 19:40:47.104629 2020] [:error] [pid 4284] [remote 127.0.0.1:18388]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Jan 16 19:40:47.104636 2020] [:error] [pid 4284] [remote 127.0.0.1:18388]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jan 16 19:40:47.104640 2020] [:error] [pid 4284] [remote 127.0.0.1:18388]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Thu Jan 16 19:40:47.104645 2020] [:error] [pid 4284] [remote 127.0.0.1:18388]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Thu Jan 16 19:40:47.104649 2020] [:error] [pid 4284] [remote 127.0.0.1:18388]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Thu Jan 16 19:40:47.104655 2020] [:error] [pid 4284] [remote 127.0.0.1:18388]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
[Thu Jan 16 19:40:47.104658 2020] [:error] [pid 4284] [remote 127.0.0.1:18388]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Thu Jan 16 19:40:47.104672 2020] [:error] [pid 4284] [remote 127.0.0.1:18388] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:46.365964 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4279] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:47.478417 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 4716] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:47.494121 2020] [so:warn] [pid 4716] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:47.496176 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 4716] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:47.496186 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 4716] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:47.496728 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 4716] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:47.496790 2020] [:warn] [pid 4716] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:47.496794 2020] [:warn] [pid 4716] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.8.
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:47.498977 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4716] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:47.498995 2020] [core:notice] [pid 4716] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.530525 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=4721): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/educess/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.530599 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=4721): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/educess/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531288 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531332 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/current/app/educess/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531337 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531344 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531347 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531353 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531356 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531362 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531365 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531371 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531374 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     module = import_module(entry)
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531379 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531382 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531388 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531393 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531399 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Thu Jan 16 19:46:50.531414 2020] [:error] [pid 4721] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debug_toolbar'
```

Notice the ModuleNotFoundError at the end of the log. I have completely uninstalled debug_toolbar from the application as far as I know but somehow the server still believes it is present.

Any assistance that could point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1: Whether DEBUG is set to True or False in base.py, I still receive a 500 internal server error.

Edit 2: I believe the problem is to do with versioning but I don't know what to change to correct it and whether it will require me to recreate the entire project or not.

Thanks,
Joshua.

Comment: I suggest you to check among the INSTALLED_APPS and MIDDLEWARE in the settings, and ensure that you have removed any import in the urls file (this is where it is usually imported). Hope it can help you :)

Comment: Yea, I checked that lots. Very confusing... :/, I think I might switch to Heroku.

Comment: I just suggest you to add the 'django-debug-toolbar==2.0' dependency to the requirements.txt file and continue the debugging. PS: I really like Heroku :)

Comment: I just created an account and even though I have already given Amazon money I am 100% going to switch. AWS is shite in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Debug toolbar from installed apps.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #'debug_toolbar',
]
```

Remove Debug toolbar from middlewares.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
   #'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]
```

Remove Debug toolbar from urls.py.

```
urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
]
```

Remove Debug toolbar imports from application

```
#import debug_toolbar
```

Now check your application locally, if its working fine then it should work on beanstalk as well.

Comment: I did do this but that was not the problem, that debug toolbar error is no longer present. I think I will just stop using Elastic Beanstalk, atleast until they improve compatibility with later versions of Django and Wagtail. Heroku was exceptionally easy to get working, so it seems as though AWS just has some catching up to do.